# Record every keystroke and store in a file

Tags: x11, logs, keyboard, input

I need to record every keystroke and **store** in a file in the user directory ~, when using my account, I am not sudoer and I cannot install programs (like [logKeys](https://code.google.com/p/logkeys/)) in any way. How could I do so using terminal?

**NOTE:** This question it's not a duplicate of the other mention question; in this question I'm asking about every keystroke, while in the other the asker asked about keystroke in terminal session.

Comment: Do you mean any key character/byte coming from a given terminal device, or any key press/release even from any keyboard connected to the host computer?

Comment: Every connected kryboard

Comment: Are you talking about things like local terminal & remote connections via SSH, or something on an X desktop?

Comment: In the Local machine

Comment: @etherfish it is not a duplicate because, I don't mean only in terminal session, but every keystroke, also in desktop, when no program is running.

Comment: In a GUI (X11) session? Or on a Linux console? What's a terminal got to do with this, since you don't want only a record of what you typed in a terminal?

Comment: @AlessioMTX You're correct. My mistake.

Comment: @Gilles in a GUI (X11) session, everything I type. Xinput is good, but is there a default UNIX tool to perform this?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`xinput test` can report all keyboard events to the X server. On a GNU system:

```
xinput list |
  grep -Po 'id=\K\d+(?=.*slave\s*keyboard)' |
  xargs -P0 -n1 xinput test
```

If you want to get key names from the key codes, you could post-process that output with:

```
awk 'BEGIN{while (("xmodmap -pke" | getline) > 0) k[$2]=$4}
     {print $0 "[" k[$NF] "]"}'
```

Add `> file.log` to store in a log file. Or `| tee file.log` to both log and see it.

`xinput` queries the XinputExtension of the X server. That's as close as you're going to get as a standard (I am not aware of any standard that covers X utilities) or common command to do that. That also does not require root privileges.

If the X server and xinput support version 2 of the XinputExtension, you can use `test-xi2` instead of `test` which gives more information, in particular the state of the modifiers (shift, ctrl, alt...). Example:

```
$ xinput test-xi2 --root
EVENT type 2 (KeyPress)
    device: 11 (11)
    detail: 54
    flags:
    root: 846.80/451.83
    event: 846.80/451.83
    buttons:
    modifiers: locked 0 latched 0 base 0x4 effective: 0x4
    group: locked 0 latched 0 base 0 effective: 0
    valuators:
    windows: root 0x26c event 0x26c child 0x10006e6
```

You can translate the keycode (in `detail`) to a keysym with the help of `xmodmap -pke` again, and the `effective` modifier bitmask to something more helpful with the help of `xmodmap -pm`. For instance:

```
xinput test-xi2 --root | perl -lne '
  BEGIN{$"=",";
    open X, "-|", "xmodmap -pke";
    while (<X>) {$k{$1}=$2 if /^keycode\s+(\d+) = (\w+)/}
    open X, "-|", "xmodmap -pm"; <X>;<X>;
    while (<X>) {if (/^(\w+)\s+(\w*)/){($k=$2)=~s/_[LR]$//;$m[$i++]=$k||$1}}
    close X;
  }
  if (/^EVENT type.*\((.*)\)/) {$e = $1}
  elsif (/detail: (\d+)/) {$d=$1}
  elsif (/modifiers:.*effective: (.*)/) {
    $m=$1;
    if ($e =~ /^Key/){
      my @mods;
      for (0..$#m) {push @mods, $m[$_] if (hex($m) & (1<<$_))}
      print "$e $d [$k{$d}] $m [@mods]"
    }
  }'
```

would output:

```
KeyPress 24 [q] 0x19 [Shift,Alt,Num_Lock]
```

when I press Shift+Alt+q when num-lock is on.

Note that you don't need to have super-user  privileges to *install* a program. If you have write access to somewhere on the file system where execute permission is granted (your home directory, `/tmp`, `/var/tmp`...) then you can copy an `xinput` command from a compatible system there and execute it.

Comment: It is very good, the output is key press n1
key press n2 key release ..Is there a way to show the letter instad of number? And how to store in a file the "log"? PS: unfortunatelly my PC doesn't have this program installed by default, and I can't install anything at the moment, I tried on another PC.

Comment: Moreover the number can't recognize if I'm using 2 or "

Comment: @AlessioMTX, all key presses will be logged though including the Shift and Capslock ones. See also my edit for key labels/symbols instead of keycodes.

Comment: Ok, I'm taking a look!

Comment: Me too, he deserve +50, but unfortunatelly I haven't finished tests with his solution.

Comment: What should I do if I get this error message? "unable to find device --root"

Comment: @AlessioMTX, you'll need `xinput` `1.6.1` or newer for `--root`. X utilities can be downloaded individually from http://xorg.freedesktop.org/releases/individual/app/. If you don't want to compile from source. Debian has a [xinput 1.6.1](https://packages.debian.org/xinput) for several architectures for Linux or kfreebsd.

Comment: awk result is /bin/sh: 1: xmodmap: not found. What should I do?

Comment: @AlessioMTX, that's meant for events to the X server. `xmodmap` has been in the reference X implementation since 1987 at least. What system are we talking about here? Could it be that `xmodmap` is not in your `$PATH` (`/usr/dt/bin` or other?).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas May I use a lightly modified version of this perl script in a program that I'm writing?

Comment: @NonnyMoose, sure, on the [general stackexchange terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange)

Comment: When piping through `awk` to `tee`, I found it necessary to prevent output buffering, either by calling `awk` with `stdbuf` (`stdbuf -o0 awk ...`) or by adding a `system("")` call within the `awk` script.

Comment: @ivan What awk implementation did you use? I found that neither of your tricks did not work with `mawk` (1.3.4), but you could use `-Winteractive` option with it or `unbuffer -p` from expect package (in Ubuntu at least). For other implementations I tried also `stdbuf -oL` works (and the `unbuffer -p` trick) .

Comment: Do all recent systems support version 2 of the XinputExtension? At least Ubuntu seems to support it, but what can you expect?

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using the [`script`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) command?

Comment: It is not what I'm looking for. I read from the link but it is only for terminal session.