# monitoring events (keyboard, mouse) in X

Tags: xorg, keyboard, mouse, events

Is it possible to display all events that are generated in Xorg? Such as keyboard pressed, mouse events...?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

A pretty quick search would likely yield [`xev`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/xev.1.xhtml) as a result. It will not show you everything that is pressed or typed in X ever. But rather, will allow you to see information about keycodes and mouse movements.

However, with the `-root` option, you might be able to get `xev` to monitor the whole X session. Note, if you do this, you'll make it pretty difficult to actually interact with any program since `xev` will be capturing all input.

`xev -root` comes with an implied "YMMV". Another possible solution is to use [`xinput`](http://www.x.org/archive/current/doc/man/man1/xinput.1.xhtml) to get the job done (though you need a recent version (1.6.1 or above)):

```
$ xinput test-xi2 --root
```

While the above should be able to capture *all* events, if your `xinput` doesn't support `test-xi2` or `--root`, you can use `xinput test` on a particular *keyboard* or *mouse* device.

See also this other question: [Record every keystroke and store in a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/129159/22565)

Comment: Actually, `xev` should show you *all* events... it's just that it only monitors one window at a time. Perhaps one could hack a script to launch multiple copies of `xev` each monitoring one window so that you end up monitoring all of them?

Comment: xev and xinput test don't show you touch events while xinput test-xi2 does.

Comment: @dkreuter, I have added your qualification inline.

Comment: *"However, with the -root option, you might be able to get xev to monitor the whole X session."* <= This is wrong. This way, `xev` will only capture events on the "root window", i.e. normally your desktop background. `xinput` is the correct solution for capturing all events regardless of the currently active window.