# Custom shortcut print key

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a keyboard without the `>` and `<` keys, which sucks when I try to write code. In windows I could `alt+numpad + 60/62` to print those keys, but that doesn't work on linux, so I'm trying to make a custom shortcut for it.

According to https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html:

> The command name that you type should be a valid system command. You can check that the command works by opening a Terminal and typing it in there. The command that opens an application cannot have the same name as the application itself.

So I tried `echo "<"` and `print "<"`, but without success is there another command that prints a key or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to bind some keys to `<` and `>` system-wide. The easiest way to accomplish that is with `xmodmap` program.

For example, on my keyboard `<` and `>` are shifted `,` and `.`, if you like that try to put

```
keysym comma = comma less
keysym period = period greater
```

into a file `~.xmodmaprc` and run `xmodmap ~/.xmodmaprc`

If you want to bind them to something else look out for keysym names in the header file `/usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h` and as usual `man xmodmap` is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

The `xev` application can be used for getting the key codes when you press keys.

See also this question: [monitoring events (keyboard, mouse) in X](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146287/monitoring-events-keyboard-mouse-in-x)