# Is there a way to log key presses under linux?

Tags: logs, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, logger

I am a heavy *Vim* user and I also use a ton of **tmux** and a load of `bash` in my everyday computer activities.

In order to optimize my work flow, even more, I would like a way to get a log of all key presses, I do during my computer sessions.

What I am looking for is a program that would work something like this:

> ```
> keylogger -o log.txt | bash
> ```
>
> And then everything I type in my bash session gets logged, to
>   `log.txt`. Where `log.txt` ends up something like this:
>
> ```
> tmux<cr>
> vi wefwef.c<cr>
> iHello, world!<esc>
> VUoHAHAHAHAHAHA hahahah!<esc>hhllb
> :!grep -a 66 /usr/bin/vi | aplay<cr>
> :x<cr>
> cat wefwef.txt<cr>
> make war<cr>
> echo vivivi is the editor of the beast!!<cr>
> yes | rm -rf /<cr>
> ps -A | grep '[0-9]\+' -o | xargs kill -9<cr>
> exit 666<cr>
> ```

… And then I can use this information to optimize my workflow even more!

Is there an Unix tool similar to the one I described?

Comment: See [Record every keystroke and store in a file](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/129159)

Answer (score 0):

From `zsh`, you could do something like:

```
cmd="stty rows $LINES cols $COLUMNS; stty '$(stty -g)'; bash"
STTY='raw -echo' cat > typescript.in | script -c "$cmd"
```

Then you'd have what you typed in `typescript.in` and the output in `typescript`.